# How to deal with special characters in a string

Tags: string, encryption, variables, mcrypt

I have a php script creating an encoded value, for example:

```
m>^æ–S[J¯vÖ_ÕÚuÍÔ'´äœÈ‘ ®@M©t²#÷[Éå¹UçfU5T°äÙ“©”ˆÇVÝ] [’e™a«Ã°7#dÉJ>
```

I then need to decode this in a vb.net application
The problem is that value above can have any characters.  And VB.net can't handle it:

```
dim strCryptedString As String = 'm>^æ–S[J¯vÖ_ÕÚuÍÔ'´äœÈ‘ ®@M©t²#÷[Éå¹UçfU5T°äÙ“©”ˆÇVÝ] [’e™a«Ã°7#dÉJ>"
```

So any suggestions how to deal with that value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try base64encode and base64decode.   That may be all that you need!

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked out like a charm.  Now I have to work on the Decryption part.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need to have it written out in your VB.net source code, you could try base64 encoding it:

```
dim strCryptedString As String = Base64Decode('bT5ew6bigJNTW0rCr3bDll/DlcOadcONw5QnwrTDpMWTw4jigJggwq5ATcKpdMKyI8O3W8OJw6XCuVXDp2ZVNVTCsMOkw5nigJzCqeKAncuGw4dWw51dIFvigJll4oSiYcKPwqvDg8KwNyNkw4lKPg==');
```

I'm not sure what the library functions' real names are.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the string, read it into a byte array instead of a string. Then use the numeric value for the characters when you do the decoding.